# Данные с базы данных не сохраняются в листе

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

Нужно сохранять информацию из таблицы SQL базы данных в лист однако почему-то данные не сохраняются, я понимаю что возможно проблема в асинхронности но не знаю как ее решить.
Буду очень рад подсказке и/или совету.

```
const conn = mysql.createConnection({

    host: "d26893.mysql.zonevs.eu",
    user: "d26893_busstops",
    password: "3w7PYquFJhver0!KdOfF",
    database: "d26893_busstops"

});

const arr = [];

conn.connect( err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }

    else {
        console.log("Database is OK");
    }
});

let query = "SELECT * FROM GN_busStops LIMIT 10";

conn.query(query, (err, result, field) => {
    arr.push(result);
});

conn.end( err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }

    else {
        console.log("Database is Close");
        console.log(arr) То есть вот здесь выдается список из 10 объектов
    }
});

console.log(arr) А здесь уже пустой лист
```

Ответ вот такой:

```
[]
Database is OK
Database is Close
[
  [
    RowDataPacket {
      stop_id: 24417,
      stop_code: '7800232-1',
      stop_name: 'Keeri',
      stop_lat: '58.32272839',
      stop_lon: '26.50336311',
      zone_id: '24417',
      alias: '',
      stop_area: 'Nõo vald',
      stop_desc: 'Nõgiaru suunas',
      lest_x: '6467416.50',
      lest_y: '646655.50',
      zone_name: '',
      authority: 'Tartu MV'
    },
    RowDataPacket {
      stop_id: 24420,
      stop_code: '7801039-1',
      stop_name: 'Valli',
      stop_lat: '58.30022338',
      stop_lon: '26.4713277',
      zone_id: '24420',
      alias: '',
      stop_area: 'Nõo vald',
      stop_desc: 'Meeri suunas',
      lest_x: '6464842.05',
      lest_y: '644871.94',
      zone_name: '',
      authority: 'Tartu MV'
    },
    RowDataPacket {
      stop_id: 9566,
      stop_code: '33704-1',
      stop_name: 'Kotka',
      stop_lat: '59.54100552',
      stop_lon: '25.73676559',
      zone_id: '9566',
      alias: '',
      stop_area: 'Kuusalu vald',
      stop_desc: '',
      lest_x: '6601655.00',
      lest_y: '598244.62',
      zone_name: 'Harju4',
      authority: 'Harjumaa ÜTK'
    },
    RowDataPacket {
      stop_id: 785,
      stop_code: '00101-1',
      stop_name: 'Kakumäe',
      stop_lat: '59.45913844',
      stop_lon: '24.5731759',
      zone_id: '785',
      alias: '',
      stop_area: 'Haabersti',
      stop_desc: '',
      lest_x: '6591401.27',
      lest_y: '532504.33',
      zone_name: 'Harju1',
      authority: 'Tallinna TA'
    },
    RowDataPacket {
      stop_id: 1181,
      stop_code: '09704-1',
      stop_name: 'Standard',
      stop_lat: '59.44800268',
      stop_lon: '24.7113414',
      zone_id: '1181',
      alias: '',
      stop_area: 'Põhja-Tallinn',
      stop_desc: '',
      lest_x: '6590235.78',
      lest_y: '540352.48',
      zone_name: 'Harju1',
      authority: 'Tallinna TA'
    },
    RowDataPacket {
      stop_id: 790,
      stop_code: '00106-1',
      stop_name: 'Teeotsa',
      stop_lat: '59.45375589',
      stop_lon: '24.58079798',
      zone_id: '790',
      alias: '',
      stop_area: 'Haabersti',
      stop_desc: '',
      lest_x: '6590805.37',
      lest_y: '532941.76',
      zone_name: 'Harju1',
      authority: 'Tallinna TA'
    },
    RowDataPacket {
      stop_id: 792,
      stop_code: '00108-1',
      stop_name: 'Sooranna tee',
      stop_lat: '59.45198095',
      stop_lon: '24.58396721',
      zone_id: '792',
      alias: '',
      stop_area: 'Haabersti',
      stop_desc: '',
      lest_x: '6590609.20',
      lest_y: '533123.23',
      zone_name: 'Harju1',
      authority: 'Tallinna TA'
    },
    RowDataPacket {
      stop_id: 134330,
      stop_code: '6500907-1',
      stop_name: 'Roosimäe',
      stop_lat: '58.05830911',
      stop_lon: '27.06492176',
      zone_id: '134330',
      alias: '',
      stop_area: 'Põlva vald',
      stop_desc: 'Põlva bussijaama suunas',
      lest_x: '6439362.30',
      lest_y: '680877.90',
      zone_name: '',
      authority: 'Põlva MV'
    },
    RowDataPacket {
      stop_id: 794,
      stop_code: '00124-1',
      stop_name: 'Landi',
      stop_lat: '59.44870712',
      stop_lon: '24.59001154',
      zone_id: '794',
      alias: '',
      stop_area: 'Haabersti',
      stop_desc: '',
      lest_x: '6590247.49',
      lest_y: '533469.27',
      zone_name: 'Harju1',
      authority: 'Tallinna TA'
    },
    RowDataPacket {
      stop_id: 795,
      stop_code: '00110-1',
      stop_name: 'Landi',
      stop_lat: '59.44885072',
      stop_lon: '24.58997753',
      zone_id: '795',
      alias: '',
      stop_area: 'Haabersti',
      stop_desc: '',
      lest_x: '6590263.47',
      lest_y: '533467.20',
      zone_name: 'Harju1',
      authority: 'Tallinna TA'
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Все действия со списком нужно делать в `npm start()`, если конечно не будет ошибки...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)